# start oracle .sql script through SQLcl on a remote windows host

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

On an Oracle database server, I have been able to schedule a nightly job that runs oracle scripts initiated from a powershell script which has this line:

```
sqlplus accountID/password @C:\scripts\run_scripts.sql
```

Now I need to achieve the same on another windows machine where the only thing of Oracle is the SQLcl client.  I am able to invoke the `initial_script.sql` SQL script, but only interactively so far through three steps:

```
PS C:\sql_scripts> sql /nolog
SQL> connect id_maint/password@111.22.33.44:1521/sid
Connected.
SQL> @initial_script.sql
```

What I need is to have the oracle initial_script.sql script started from powershell.  I have two hurdles.

1. To connect to the remote database, I have to first get the SQLcl's SQL> prompt via the `PS> sql /nolog` command at the powershell command prompt, and then run the `SQL> connect id_maint/password@111.22.33.44:1521/sid` command at the SQL> prompt.
2. `SQL> connect id_maint/password@111.22.33.44:1521/sid` works fine.  But I need to invoke the oracle script initial_script.sql at the same time.  However,

```
SQL> connect id_maint/password@111.22.33.44:1521/sid @C:\sql_scripts\initial_script.sql
```

incurs an error.

So what I am seeking is to get three things done (get the SQL> prompt -> connect to the remote database -> invoke the oracle script), all initiated by a power script at the PS> prompt.

Appreciated it very much if someone can help me out.

Comment: Why are you separating the launching of the script in 3 lines? Why not just use `sql id_maint/password@111.22.33.44:1521/sid @C:\sql_scripts\initial_script.sql`? The same way as your first command just `sql` instead of `sqlplus`.

Comment: Wonderful!  It works!  That is exactly what I was looking for!  I did not know that because SQLcl is new to me.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! I'll put it into an answer so you can mark the question answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLcl is 99% compatible with SQLPlus so for almost any `sqlplus` command you should be able to just use `sql`.

Launch the script using your existing `sqlplus` command but using `sql` instead

`sql id_maint/password@111.22.33.44:1521/sid @C:\sql_scripts\initial_script.sql`